# Async Thunk Error Messages in React with toast.error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I've implemented an asynchronous login thunk with error handling. The success message appears correctly, but the error message does not.

```js
export const loginThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'login',
  async (credentials: { email: string; password: string }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const res = await api.post('/api/login', credentials)
      return res.data
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response?.data)
      }
    }
  }
)

extraReducers: (builder) => {
    //** Login */
    builder.addCase(loginThunk.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true
    })
    builder.addCase(loginThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload.user
      state.isLoggedIn = true
      state.isLoading = false
    })
    builder.addCase(loginThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
      const errorMsg = action.payload
      if (typeof errorMsg === 'string') {
        state.error = errorMsg
      }
      state.isLoading = false
      return state
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createAsyncThunks` Thunks will ***always*** return a resolved Promise. The `onSubmitHandler` should unwrap the resolved Promise returned by the `loginThunk` action to determine if the action was successful or if there was an error.

For details see:

- [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results)
- [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors)

You can handle the error in the Promise chain:

```js
const onSubmitHandler = (e: FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  dispatch(loginThunk(credentials))
    .unwrap()
    .then((res) => {
      const { message, token } = res.payload;
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      toast.success(message);
      navigate('/');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      let errorMessage = 'Something went wrong';

      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        const errorMessage = error.response?.data.msg;
      }

      toast.error(errorMessage);
    });
};
```

Or in the `try/catch` with `async/await`:

```js
const onSubmitHandler = async (e: FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  try {
    const res = await dispatch(loginThunk(credentials)).unwrap();

    const { message, token } = res.payload;
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    toast.success(message);
    navigate('/');
  } catch (error) {
    let errorMessage = 'Something went wrong';

    if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
      const errorMessage = error.response?.data.msg;
    }

    toast.error(errorMessage);
  }
};
```